# Alternative to \mathcal and \mathscr

Tags: fonts

Does anyone know of the font that will produce the capital letter "O" as follows?:

[image: wanted capital letter "O"]

It is just slightly different from the "O" made with `\mathcal` and `\mathscr`.

Answer (score 13):

```
\usepackage{eucal}
$\mathcal{O}$
```

Answer (score 10):

My preferred method of using this typeface:

```
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
$\mathscr O$
```

Comment: In fact, `eucal` and `euscript` are identical, except that they use different commands (`\mathcal` and `\mathscr`).

Comment: This is to be expected (that `O` is pretty distinctive, after all); I presented this because I am loath to override the mathcal typeface provided by (iirc) AMSmath.